# Cluster solution for geographically distributed database

Tags: database, cluster-computing, replication, distributed, geo

What is the best solution for geographically distributed database cluster?
I mean if we need something like an online chat, photo sharing, comments and so on.
I have found a solution called "Galera Cluster" that supports active-active replication out of the box which is really cool but I am not sure that it is the best solution.
For me the obvious problems for such geo-distributed applications are following:
1. I think that it is too hard to create good active-active replication. Just because there will be so many replication (one server changes than all servers must be updated).
2. We have to store too many unnecessary data. If we have 5 database master servers around the world then we will store 5 times more data than if we have one database server.
What do you think about these problems? Is there any tools which can help you control replication level, manage your cluster and so on?
Best Regards, Alexnadr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there multi master database with customizable replication level?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986610/is-there-multi-master-database-with-customizable-replication-level)